# Onfocus and off-focus textbox

Tags: jquery, html

I am written a jquery script that automatically detects on the number that a user has entered. If the user has entered 2,4,6,8,10 - they will automatically have a confirm box popping up stating that there is an offer.

If they click YES, they get redirected. However, if they click Cancel, it focuses back on the textbox and the confirm box appears again.

Is there anyway i can make it so if a user clicks on CANCEL, the focus is off the textbox so no loop of confirm box occurs.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="Quantity" id="Quantity9438851" name="Quantity" value="1" style="width:30px">
```

JQUERY

```
$("#Quantity9438851").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
    if($(this).val() == 2){
     var didConfirm = confirm("There is currently an offer for 2 polo shirt for £25. Click YES to recieve discount.");
      if (didConfirm == true) {
        window.location.href = "http://blahblah.com/&Quantity=10";
      }
    }else if($(this).val() == 4){
     var didConfirm = confirm("There is currently an offer for 4 polo shirt for £50. Click YES to recieve discount.");
      if (didConfirm == true) {
        window.location.href = "http://google.com/Registration/blah";
      }        
    }else if($(this).val() == 6){
     var didConfirm = confirm("There is currently an offer for 6 polo shirt for £75. Click YES to recieve discount.");
      if (didConfirm == true) {
        window.location.href = "http://google.com/Registration/blah";
      }                
    }else if($(this).val() == 8){
     var didConfirm = confirm("There is currently an offer for 8 polo shirt for £100. Click YES to recieve discount.");
      if (didConfirm == true) {
        window.location.href = "http://google.com/Registration/blah";
      }                
    }else if($(this).val() == 10){
     var didConfirm = confirm("There is currently an offer for 10 polo shirt for £100. Click YES to recieve discount.");
      if (didConfirm == true) {
        window.location.href = "http://google.com/Registration/blah";
      }                
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NUJrL/3/

Comment: Code improvement suggestion: `if($(this).val() % 2 === 0){ ..."There is currently an offer for" + $(this).val() + " polo..."  }`

Comment: you can focus on another item by doing if(didConfirm == true) { ... } else { ...focus on another item }. You could make the code a lot smaller too, but that is another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use the `blur` event?

```
$("#Quantity9438851").bind("blur", function() {

    var val = $(this).val();

    if(!(val % 2) && val <= 10){

      var conf = confirm("There is currently an offer for "
         + val +" polo shirt for £25. Click YES to recieve discount.");

      if (conf) 
        window.location.href = "http://google.com/&Quantity=10";


    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NUJrL/6/

Comment: Or to go one step further, just bind to `blur`. That way if the user wants to type 22 you don't pop-up the box offering them a deal on 2 before they've finished!

Comment: Going to look into that bind function. But as for now. this works perfectly!

Comment: @JSG Updated based on Daniel's comment.

Comment: The edit above implementing @danielpsc fixes - when the user now enters in the value, he has to click away. Is there anyway to show the confirm without them clicking off the textbox.

Comment: @JSG Try experimenting a bit with different events like `keyup` and let me know if it doesn't work out for you

Comment: Johan, i was just thinking of combining 'blur keyup' events together but it doesnt seem to work. Anymore advice?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38566/discussion-between-jsg-and-johan)